# Magento Built in Calendar not working in admin back end

Tags: php, javascript, magento, calendar

I am struck at a strange point..

I am maintaining a Magento store which sells flowers. I have created an option for delivery date, which is of date type. Its work fine on front end, Calendar pops up, user can select the date, can change the date, can do anything, Which is normally allowed on the Calendar..

In the back end, when I try to add an Order, I select a product, click on configure button to add add the delivery date and quantity, Calendar does not work. Although it appears when clicked on the Calendar image, but its greyed out (like it is not enabled) if I try to click on it, it just vanishes, I can't select a date, can't do even a single click on Calendar and it disappears and I am unable to create the order

interestingly, if I manually enter the date in Calendar text field, then I can create order (delivery date is a mandatory option).

I tried to dig the solution by going into phtml files, php files and ended at sale/orders/create where call to configure button is made. After this, I am unable to find product options popup (on which delivery date is selected) but I am unable to fix this issue.

I tried to get google and forum helps, but at a failure yet.

Calendar is working totally okay at front end, but its not working at backend.

Can somebody help me? Any guideline? Where I can find product option dialog? any clue? I am trying to resolve the issue for last 4 days.

**UPDATE:-**
STILL WONDERING OVER IT

now, if I set up template and block hints in Mag admin, it starts working

also, if I clear the breakpoints in admin console, it works then too

also, its not working ONLY WHEN I TRY TO CREATE AN ORDER FROM ADMIN BACKEND AND SELECT DATE THERE, in other locations at admin backend it works

so much annoying, please help me, its more then weeks now...
Thanks.

Comment: In admin, do you have any error in you JS console? What version of magento are you using?

Comment: thanks for hint, I tried using fire bug and found this

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined calendar.js:1660
Date.parseDate calendar.js:1660
triggerEl.(anonymous function)

Comment: are you using any service the minify javascript ?

Comment: Did you try to clean JS/CSS cache?

Comment: @Meabed I dont think that I am using any javascript service..

Comment: @YaroslavRogoza I have disabled the cache, and I have tried to clear the cache too..

Comment: @YaroslavRogoza after clearing JS/CSS cache, calendar is not showing at all

Comment: link to ur website we could debug whats going on?

Comment: http://www.flowermuse.com, but the issue is, its working on front end, and calculator is not working at back end..store is live..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/17592/15064

Edit js/calendar/calendar-setup.js and add :

```
else cal.showAt(params.position[0],params.position[1]);
cal.element.style.zIndex = 99999; // Fix for admin "create order"
return false;}
```

Fix worked for me on Magento 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the backend under: `System > Configuration > Developer > JavaScript Settings > Merge JavaScript Files` and be sure to disable it.

If it is enabled, this might be your problem.

http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/why-you-shouldnt-merge-javascript-in-magento.html

Comment: Thanks for you help...its already disabled ...and issue is with back end..on front end , calculator is just working as it should...in backend calculator is not working at all..

Comment: then, something is broken. No idea on that from outside, sorry.

Comment: also, if in firebug console, I clear the breakpoint error, calendar still works